# Java Generics type to have an specific annotation

Tags: java, generics

I have a class which should have a typed parameter. Is it possible for me to ensure that the `type` should have a particular annotation? Below is what I'm trying to achieve. But it doesn't work. Is there any other way in which we can mandate the `type` to have a particular annotation? Version of Java is 1.6

```
abstract class Test<T extends javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement>{
    public abstract T unmarshall();
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "user", namespace = "abc.com")
class User{
    //Some fields
}

class Test extends Test<User>{
    public User unmarshall(){
        //unarshall
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no inheritance on annotations and therefore, you can't check if your generic type is annotated with `@XmlRootElement`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that in plain JAVA. But with AspectJ I think you could do that (at least some years ago I could generate compile errors and show them in Eclipse when something was wrong annotated).